# What am I doing wrong in calculating $i^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$i^2 = i \cdot i = (\sqrt{-1}) \cdot (\sqrt{-1}) = ({\sqrt{-1}})^2 = -1   \tag{1}$$
$$i^2 = i \cdot i = \underbrace{\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)}}_{?} = \sqrt{(-1)^2} = 1   \tag{2}$$

What are the conceptual or logical errors here?

TIA

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has two square roots.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: It's also true for real number...